# Stop printing test page everytime on HP PSC 1410

Tags: 10.10, printing, hp

Everytime I switch on my desktop running and start the HP PSC 1410, it will print a test page. I have recently installed the hplip driver (the latest one on the hplip website) and the driver installed correctly.

I dont know what `pp-build=no` is, but it was mentioned somewhere that it should be `=yes`. please suggest what to do to stop this test page printing everytime. I have tried putting the test page on scanner and scanned a couple of times to align the cartridges but that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is not specific to Ubuntu.

It seems that page will keep printing until you complete the alignment test. It seems to be an involved procedure. See this example:
http://www.fixya.com/support/t141507-hp_psc_1410v

I would suggest carefully reading the printer documentation, perhaps call/contact HP to get assistance.